# SQL loader join date and time into single column

Tags: oracle, datetime, sql-loader

I have a csv file to load that has a date and a time separated by a comma.  I need to join these together and put them in a single date column in the oracle db table.

Example data:

```
17960152,   red,1994-05-14,23.00.00
38424235,   blue,1996-05-10,12.36.28
```

This is oversimplified; there are millions of rows and other data fields (including many more dates without this issue).

Can someone help me get the loader to read only this comma as not being a delimiter?

I have tried the following control file:

```
OPTIONS (SKIP=0, direct=true)
LOAD DATA
    INFILE "..\test.csv" BADFILE ".\test.bad" DISCARDFILE ".\test.dis"
INSERT
INTO TABLE table_test
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
    TRAILING NULLCOLS
    ( 
        cust_ID,
        cust_TYPE,
        cust_date1       filler,
        cust_date2      DATE "hh24:mi:ss" "to_date(:cust_date1,'yyyy-mm-dd') + :cust_date2",
    )
```

Error is:

```
SQL*Loader-291: Invalid bind variable cust_date1 in SQL string for column cust_date2.
```

Comment: Gave up trying to find a way and just used extra columns and merged them then dropped the extras later.  Had hoped for a cleaner solution....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mark the fields in the data as BOUNDFILLER which means save them for later use. Be sure to give them a name that does not match a column in the table.  Then, for the column name, combine them with an expression that converts them to a date:

```
OPTIONS (SKIP=0, direct=true)
LOAD DATA
    INFILE "..\test.csv" BADFILE ".\test.bad" DISCARDFILE ".\test.dis"
INSERT
INTO TABLE table_test
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
    TRAILING NULLCOLS
    ( 
        cust_ID,
        cust_TYPE,
        X_DATE     BOUNDFILLER,
        X_TIME     BOUNDFILLER,
        cust_date  EXPRESSION "TO_DATE(:X_DATE || ' ' || :X_TIME, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24.MI.SS')"
    )
```